# AJAX call not being executed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I just come arround the corner with AJAX calls and trying to learn it. I have a form i am trying to push through an AJAX call, but getting a constant error it can't send, and I cant wrap my head arround it why it doesn't work.

Form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="contact-form"  method="post">
      <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Naam" class="form-control input-lg">                                
             </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
             <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email adres" class="form-control input-lg">
             </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
             <div class="controls">
                 <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="8" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Bericht"></textarea>
             </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-actions">
              <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Verstuur Bericht</button>
       </div>
       <div id="succes">
       </div>
</form>
```

The Ajax Call

```
$('form').bind('submit',function(){
    $.ajax({
        type    : 'POST',
        url     : 'inc/actions/sendmail.php',
        data    : $(this).serialize(),
        cache   : false,
        dataType: 'text',
        success : function (serverResponse) { alert('mail sent successfully.'); },
        error   : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert('error sending mail');}
    });
})
```

And the sendmail.php

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["naam"]);
$from = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["email"]);                                    
$message = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["bericht"]);

$message = wordwrap($message, 70);  
$to = "example@myemail.nl";
$subject = "Een gebruiker heeft een vraag of opmerking";

$body = "Some messages and colloring, to much to paste cause it's inline-markup";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: noreply@ajaxfailure.nl";

if ($name == ''){
    echo '<p>U heeft geen naam ingevuld</p>';    
}else if($from == ''){
    echo '<p>U heeft geen emailadres achter gelaten</p>';
}else if($body == ''){
    echo '<p>U heeft geen bericht ingevuld niet ingevuld';
}else {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
        echo '<p>Uw bericht is verzonden.</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>Er is iets mis gegaan bij het verzenden van de data, probeer het opnieuw.</p>';
    }
}
```

Everytime it returns me the error alert from the AJAX call and doesnt execute anything. My console doesn't spot an error either and remains competely blank.

I checked the console as per suggestion on the network tab and it doesnt even get on the page itself. There is no 404 error on that part. It seems the request gets canceled.

[image: Screendump of console / network]

Comment: Always use a developer tool like [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) to debug your code. This way you see `exactly` was it is sent and where.

Comment: Using the Chrome Develop tool for it.

Comment: Check the network tab in chrome dev tools

Comment: Please look into the javascript console after making the change i suggested - it will give you the error. The request was cancelled because of a php error probably

Comment: It had to do with refreshing probably (didnt disable the default state of the button) and had to do some rebindng on the form by grabbing the id instead of element. I get the correct message now, just not the mail yet, but thats probably a matter of debugging in my PHP.

Comment: first thing, can't you change your ajax code to get you the actual error message instead of your "'error sending mail'" ?

Comment: I already did, but not needed anymore, cause it works. It logs now in console, but my last error was with retrieving the `POST`, had to make a `REQUEST` for it instead of finding the `POST` variable. Problem solved. Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AJAX request is being cancelled because immediately after the AJAX is initiated, your form does its standard form submission, with the browser reloading the page. You need to either return false or prevent default, in the submit event:

```
$('form').bind('submit',function(){
    ...
    ...
    return false;
});
```

Or capture the event and prevent default:

```
$('form').bind('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
    ...
});
```

Either of the above will stop the form from submitting and allow your AJAX request to complete.

Comment: Yes, i actually disabled the button through the form to prevent an action. I had just added that when you posted it

Answer (score 2):

Your input name attributes dont match with your php:

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["name"]); //<-- not 'naam'
$from = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["email"]);                                    
$message = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["message"]); //<-- not 'bericht'
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing those out. It didnt solve it yet, but one step closer. Its what you get when you mingle Dutch and English together

Comment: @Dorvalla in your error function, replace alert with `console.log(errorThrown);` and check in the js console for the actual error, then edit your question with the result

Answer (score 1):

Edit this

```
$('#contact-form').bind('submit',function(){
```

The ajax-function did not bind to the element.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers, I think you can't use `this` in this line:

```
data : $(this).serialize(),
```

Try using:

```
data : $('form').serialize(),
```

Comment: I think this was the last push to put me in the right direction combined with the other awnsers. I cant accept them all as answers, but at least I get the send message, and it connects to the sendmail.php. I now just have to debug that one in order to get it working